# Conditional AndroidManifest attribute based on build profile?

Tags: android, gradle

I'd like to release a demo and a full version of my app.

How can I:

- define different build profiles so that if I build the `apk` I get two apps, one full and one for demo?
- Change the `<application android:label="@string/app_name">`? Eg for full version I want to use `@String/app_name`, but for demo build profile use `app_name_demo`? The app names are also localized!

Do I somehow have to work with the `gradle` *productFlavors* part?

Like:

```
   productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix "-demo"
        }
    }
```

But I could not find how to achieve my points above.

Comment: it sounds like you want to use productFlavors, one thing though, each build variant has its own apk

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
go with productFlavors

```
productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix "-Demo"

        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false

        }
    }
```

Create two folder under /app/src 
1. demo
2. release

place constant.xml file and put your application label there accordingly. Based on your build type your application name would be picked up.

also inside each product flavour folder you can create the same directory structure as you would do with app main folder.

So your final structure would go like

```
/demo/res/values/constant.xml
/demo/res/values-fr/constant.xml
```

something like this.

Comment: And how can I add localization values under those folders? Currently I have `values/strings.xml` and `values-fr/string.xml`. Of course I also want to change the `app_name_demo` for all localizations.

Comment: I think what you're suggesting is bad practice, build types are meant to be used for different configuration of the same app, if you want to differentiate 2 versions of the app based on different functionalities (like demo/full) you should use flavors